# Python / Pandas / compare 2 excel sheet / problem with the results

Tags: excel, pandas

In my excel file here is my sheet1 :

```
a
2
3
4
b
```

Sheet 2 :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pds
import numpy as np
df1= pds.read_excel('/gdrive/MyDrive/file.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
df2= pds.read_excel('/gdrive/MyDrive/file.xlsx',sheet_name=1)
comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)
for item in zip(rows,cols):
    print(item[0],item[1])
```

The result is :

```
3 0
```

But I was expecting

```
0 0
5 0
```

Why is there such a difference ?

Comment: `Header=None` in the `read_excels` maybe, you'd get 0,0 and 4,0. (there is no row 5 in your example it is 0-indexed.)

Comment: Yep it worked. But I don't understand why there is this header things as the sheets belong to the same file

Comment: It thinks the first row is a header by default so it goes into the dataframe as a header not a row, and never gets compared to the other df's header row. The fact they are in the same file has nothing to do with it, it is just default pandas behavior.